# window.gtag function for an event doesn't make data show up on GA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, gtag.js

I have two scenarios - the first one is to send a `page_view` info to GA. The second one, which is causing the problem, is to send an `event` with some custom properties and data upon a form submission. The following is what I'm doing:

First scenario (works fine):

```
const pageViewFunction = (path) => {
   window.gtag('config', 'G-SOME_ID', {
     page_path: path
   });
};
```

This function works as expected upon getting invoked, i.e., I can see that page's information showing up on GA after the page loads.

Second scenario (doesn't work):

```
const postData = (someParam) => {
  window.gtag('event', 'myEventName', {
    event_category: 'something_something',
    event_label: 'test',
    value: someParam
  });
};
```

This function, just like the first `page_view` function, makes a successful POST request to the `https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?<params>` endpoint when invoked. As such, I can also see the `event_category`, `event_label` and `value` props under the `Query String Parameters` section in the network tab. However, despite waiting for several hours, I cannot see the `myEventName` event show up under `All Events -> Events -> Existing Events` section on my GA console.

I do have the following setup in my root level `index.html` file's `<head>` tag so it should be good on that front:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-SOME-ID></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', ‘G-SOME-ID’);
    </script>
```

I've referred to the [gtag docs](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/api#event) for this and it seems like I'm doing as instructed. Any advice as to how to make this event data show up on GA would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics Event **Value** field only accepts **integers**, what do you set in `someParam` ?

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en